# Change Sound Juicer's CD Database

Tags: configuration, database, sound-juicer

I like sound juicer for ripping CDs, but the cd-database of music brainz is very scrappy compared to freedb.org. I wanted to change the source of the database but unfortunately I didn't find any config-file.

Is there any way to change it or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that Sound Juicer which tries to use MusicBrainz is busted, at least as of 13.10.

I don't know how to modify it to use freedb.org.

However, there is a similar program called Asunder which uses CDDB:

`sudo apt-get install asunder`

In action:

[image]

Asunder also has nice configuration options for encoding to OGG, MP3, FLAC and even AAC.

Comment: As a bonus asunder uses cdparanoia for a perfect rip. Thanks for the tip!